# bootstrap rails drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, partial

I'm having difficulty trying to get a dropdown box in rails using the bootstrap framework.

```
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Categories<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

<!--  trying to insert dynamic list for drop down -->

        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

     <li><%= link_to "All Categories", categories_path %></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

I figured it would be similiar to the `<ul>` list `</ul>` from index

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>

    <li><%= category.name %></li>
<%end >
```

But the rails says .each is not defined...  my dropdown is in a _partial html file.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: `each is not defined`, it likely specifies that each is not defined for `nil:NilClass` right? how are you defining `@categories` ?

Comment: You should be passing in a `categories` variable to your partial, and using that. It's always better to explicitly pass a partials dependencies into a partial than to rely on the presence of `@instance` variables.

Comment: ok, the @categories variable is in the category controller.  I can access it from the index.hmtl.erb page.  I do need to reference it somehow. 

yes. nil.Nilclass is my error.   So how do I pass this categories variable into my partial html file?

Comment: Argh, I can't seem to figure out how to pass this instance variable from my controller to my partial.  Is it OK to call one partial file from another partial file?

Answer (score 0):

When you call your partial, you should pass locals like that:

```
<%= render 'my_partial', catgories: @categories %>
```

And in your partial:

```
<% categories.each do |category|%>
     <li><%= category.name %></li>
  <% end %>
```